# new records insertion into database table in my case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rake

I am developing a **Rails v2.3** application which is **a service to search projects' information** where projects info are stored in database.

There is an existing `projects` table in the database like following:

[image]

For the sake of  satisfying customer’s requirement, this table needs to insert new data in the mid-night everyday.

**The reason of creating these new records is to make the Rails application be able to search projects by a single word besides searching by the full name.**

**For example,** if search by word "**portal**", both **Car rental portal** and **Position track portal** records should be found by the Rails application. **That's the app.'s database needs to have all the records of each single word from** `project_name`.

So, my plan is to generate those new records by **spliting the value in** `project_name` **column** (of the above `projects` table) **into single words** and then **use each single word** as a **new record's** `project_name` while keep other columns of the record unchanged.

**For example,** in above table, the first record has `project_name` "**Car rental portal**", what I gonna do is to split this string into 3 words and **construct the following three new records** to be inserted into the table:

[image]

To achieve this. I tried to make a **rake task** which gets all records from the original `projects` table, and for each record, the **rake task** splits the string value of `project_name` column into words, then construct the new records with words and insert into the table. My **rake task** looks like the code below:

```
all_records = ActiveRecord::Base.execute("select * from projects;") 
all_records.each do |record|
     user_id = record[0]
     project_name=record[1]
     department = record[2]
     other = record[3]

     words=project_name.split()

     words.each do |word|
         sql = "insert into project values (#{user_id},#{word},#{department},#{other});"
         ActiveRecord::Base.execute(sql)
     end
end
```

**The rake task works well**, it creates the expected new records and inserted into the `projects` table, **BUT** the problem is it takes **36 hours** to complete!

It is understandable since the origin table is very very large, if split the string to words and create the new record it's like create a 3 times larger table (suppose each string of `project_name` has 3 words).

**My question:**

- Could some Rails experts suggest me some more efficient way to achieve the new record insertion thing I described above?
- Or any new way to enable single word search in my case? (That's do not use the way I designed to have each single word store in the database.)

Answer (score 0):

If you do this only for searching purpose, why don't you use [Sunspot](http://outoftime.github.com/sunspot/) ? It supports full text search.

Splitting project name sounds like a really bad idea for me.

But if you want to take it less time, then I'd encourage you to split this single task into more rake tasks, that would do the same, but for other set of projects.

Answer (score 0):

For faster importing, you want to use [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import), it will speed up your execution by a couple orders of magnitude.

```
columns = [:title, :project_name, :department, :other]
values = all_records.inject([]) do |values_arr, record|

    user_id, project_name, department, other = record

    project_name.split.each do |name|
        values_arr << [user_id, name, department, other]
    end
    values_arr
end

class TempModel < ActiveRecord::Base; set_table_name "projects"; end
TempModel.import columns, values, :validate=>false
```

Comment: Hi, the projects table is actually not mapped to any model object in the project. Actually all the names are fake here compare to the real project. That's there is no model mapped to the table.

Comment: . . . so just define a model to make the rake task easier.  See my edits for an example.

Comment: Is there any rough estimation of how much faster it is compare to my design in my post? 2,3 times faster?

Comment: Besides, this activerecord-import library is used for Rails 3 and beyond, but as I mentioned in my post, I am using Rails V2.3, which is required by customer.

Comment: you can use the ar-extensions gem for 2.3 and below, it includes all the same functionality of activerecord-import

Comment: and a "couple orders of magnitude" is 100x faster